# Missing backtick from soft keypad

Tags: keyboard, special-chars

I have a HTC One S with Android version 4.0.3. On the short keypad I can't find a way to do a backtick. Am I just missing it, or is there a way to enable additional characters? (Or maybe a better soft keypad to download?)

Comment: There are [plenty of 3rd party keyboards](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=keyboard&c=apps) available, e.g. SlideIt, SwiftKey, [Swype](http://beta.swype.com/) or [Hacker's Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard)

Comment: @ce4 From your list at least SwiftKey doesn't have backticks.

Answer (score 5):

On my Galaxy Nexus with the default Android keyboard I see the backtick (aka grave) on the secondary symbol screen. <kbd>?123</kbd> then <kbd>=\<</kbd> and <kbd>`</kbd> is the second key in the top row.

I normally use SwiftKey 3, however, and I find it as one of the options on a long-press of <kbd>'</kbd> on the secondary keyboard (accessed by pressing the <kbd>123</kbd> key).

Answer (score 4):

For ***HTC*** keyboards long-pressing the <kbd>C</kbd> key brings up a list of characters to choose from including the backtick character.

[image: Long-pressing the 'C' key brings up a list of characters to chose from including the backtick character.]

Answer (score 0):

On the standard Jelly Bean keyboard, which is the next sub-version after ICS (I class a sub-version as a version in which only the number after the decimal point is incremented), you access the backtick (`) by pressing the <kbd>?123</kbd> button, the <kbd>=\<</kbd> button and then the <kbd>`</kbd> button is the second on the top row, from the left.

However, you may need to enable an extended or QWERTY keyboard - this can usually be done from the keyboard settings, which can be accessed at:

System Settings --> Language and Input --> Press the little setting icon next to your input method/keyboard.